# How to resolve "Error Encountered" in Windows 11 update?

Tags: windows-update, windows-11

I have tried to update my PC several times, Currently on Beta insider (Windows 11), and it shows this error encountered message after clicking on "Update and restart"

[image: Screenshot 1]

Then, I ran troubleshooter and it showed this message:

[image: Screenshot 2]

The error message reads: 
`Problem with BITS service : The requested service has already been started. System.Management.Automation.RemoteException More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2182. System.Management.Automation.RemoteException`

Windows 11 Pro activated,
Beta Insider opted in

I tried any help i could find on the internet, but no luck.

---

## Update

I used the Media Creation tool to reinstall windows, to see if it fixes anything. After restarting several times, it showed a message "Undoing changes made to your computer" and booted up normally, then this box appeared:

[image: Screenshot 3]

What does this mean?

Some more insight to the problem: This started when my friend borrowed my computer, and I assume he tampered with it, since I had `Windows 11 Home`, now it is `Windows 11 Pro`. I think it is some sort of crack because the data was intact.

## Update 2

I tried the option "keep nothing" while resetting, and it showed the same screen (we couldn't install windows 11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current Beta Insider build is 22581.200. (I have one Insider machine here).

22000.588 is fairly old.

*So your machine is not yet on an Insider Build.*

Make certain in Windows Update that you have enrolled in the Insider Program.

(A) There may be some issue with software you have that is not compatible with the Insider Build. Look through your software and see if there is evidence of this.

(B) Try restarting the BITS Service. Troubleshooter should have done that.

(C) Try changing the Insider Channel to Development and see if that kicks of updates.  Do a full Restart before trying to update again. You can change back to Beta later.

(D) It may take a some time for Windows to adjust the Insider builds to accommodate all computers.

(E) There are no guarantees with Insider builds (Microsoft made clear).

You can try a Windows 11 Repair Install.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

You can try (1) Keep Everything  (2) Keep Data  (3) Keep Nothing (means reinstalling Windows 11 Fresh.

Repair Install may take you back a build or two and then try updating again.

You can use link above to create a Windows 11 ISO to install Windows 11

[image: Create Windows 11 Media]

.

If enough has gone wrong, you can use the Media Creation Link and select Keep Nothing so as to install Windows 11 fresh.

Then finally, back up, look at the basic requirements (TPM V2; UEFI, CPU newer than 3 years old) and then:

**(a)** use the Windows Settings, Update, Recovery options and do a Reset.

**(b)** do a completely fresh install letting Windows 11 make its needed partitions.

Comment: `2000.588` is my current build. I switched to beta since i saw that 22581 is rolling to beta also, and didn't want to opt into dev channel.

Comment: 22000.588 is fairly old.  Current is 22H2 22581.200.   My comment about DEV channel was to try to "kickstart" updates.  You can always change back to Beta.

Comment: @IshanJ. - If you are on 22000.558 then you do NOT have an insider preview build installed on yourself machine. Additionally, vital information like that, should be contained within your question or a comment to an answer. Something has hosed Windows Update on your system, which means, you have to determine how to resolve that problem before you even think about installing an Insider Preview build.  If you still want to do that, download the current Insider Preview build ISO and use that to get into the proper release channel.

Comment: @IshanJ.  - I amended my answer to put your current build (not yet Insider to the beginning to get my answer sequence more correct given the knowledge of your current build.

Comment: Where can I get official link to the ISO @Ramhound ?

Comment: You can make the proper ISO from the Media Creation Link I gave you. Click on it and select Make Windows 11 Installation Media.

Comment: @IshanJ. - Microsoft.com

Comment: @John I have added an update to the post after trying your suggested method.

Comment: Something has certainly gone wrong.  Windows does not just "change to Pro".   You may need to reinstall Windows properly.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Go to the Media Creation Link in my answer, and at the selection point, choose Keep Nothing. That will reinstall Windows 11 fresh.  I amended my answer.

Comment: @John update #2 added to the post. Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest a complete fresh install making sure you meet all requirements.   My answer amended

Comment: I had to reset from settings. that did the trick. please update the answer, thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer to clearly add Reset.  Thanks.